# AWS Glue ETL job missing fields visible to crawler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a table created by a crawler pointing to some parquet files stored in s3. From the the Glue data catalogue GUI I can see many fields (53).

When I open up an ETL dev endpoint and connect with a sagemaker notebook, load the same table and run printSchema, I see a lot less fields (36) using the code below.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext, DynamicFrame

# Get the right stuff
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "my_database", table_name = "my_table")

print('Fields: ', len(data.schema().fields))
data.printSchema()
```

returns only 36 fields. Can anyone tell me how to access the missing fields? It seems to happen most frequently on fields that are sparsely populated.

Edit: [This unanswered question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=836628&#836628) on the AWS forums seems to be due to the same issue - apparently PySpark tries to infer its own schema rather than use the one found by the crawler.

Comment: Did you find any resolution to that?

Answer (score 1):

For parquet files Glue uses Spark's reader and therefore rely on the schema inherited from a file instead of using the one from Data Catalog created by crawler.

If source folder has files with different schemas then Glue crawler merges it into a single schema which makes it different from the one you see in ETL.

Comment: So is there any way to tell the dynamic frame to use glue data catalog only?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.create_dynamic_frame.from_options` and read directly from s3 bucket? Sometimes that behaves differently from Crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table' in 'Output -> Configuration options (optional)' section of Crawler?